# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError crash app while launching main activity

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I've recently updated Firebase and google play service in android studio but since update I am getting strange error which doesn't let main activity to launch I am only getting a few lines of LogCat without any in-app error.

**Here is my Logcat**

```
02-06 03:48:04.442 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-06 03:48:04.562 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-06 03:48:04.562 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
02-06 03:48:04.562 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
02-06 03:48:04.562 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
02-06 03:48:04.672 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener
02-06 03:48:04.672 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 292: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
02-06 03:48:04.672 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-06 03:48:04.682 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener
02-06 03:48:04.682 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 295: Landroid/app/Application;.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
02-06 03:48:04.682 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-06 03:48:04.712 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 I/ActivityThread: Pub com.example.com.application_2.firebaseinitprovider: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
02-06 03:48:04.722 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza
02-06 03:48:04.722 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 5796: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;.isDeviceProtectedStorage (Landroid/content/Context;)Z
02-06 03:48:04.722 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
02-06 03:48:04.742 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-06 03:48:04.742 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41eab378)
02-06 03:48:04.772 28081-28081/com.example.com.application_2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4602)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4232)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4174)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is my Build Gradle Files**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.application_2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;}
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
    // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Top-level build file**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I googled but i got only 8 results which is not even same as mine please help

Answer (score 2):

It's because of compatible issues between device and library. So simple downgrade your google play and Firebase service to 9.6.1.

Change this

```
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;}
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

To this

```
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'){
    force = true;}
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
```

Hope it works